# How to check Navigation Destination is in the NavController back stack or not?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

What I am exactly looking for is that wether my fragment is already in the back stack or not.

For example, I navigate to Fragment A to Fragment B. Later, I navigate to Fragment B to Fragment C. Now, I want to check in the Fragment C that is there Fragment A available in the back stack. If yes, I want to pop out all the fragments up to Fragment A else I want to add new Fragment A.

Please make sure I want to check availability of Fragment A in Fragment C.

Is there any luck?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think Navigation AAC was designed for that usecase, however you could potentially use `fragmentManager.getFragments()` and iterate through the currently added fragments.

Answer (score 5):

> What I am exactly looking for is that wether my fragment is already in
> the back stack or not.

There is a way to do that using `NavController`.

```kotlin
try {
    val back:NavBackStackEntry = controller.getBackStackEntry(R.id.nav_a)
    Log.d("in_back_stack", back.destination.label.toString())
} catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException){
    Log.d("in_back_stack","no_entry")
}
```

Using `NavController.getBackStackEntry(...)` & `destinationId` you can easily know whether a fragment is already in the back stack or not. But be careful using this method. As the method will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the `destinationId` is not found in the back stack.

> Please make sure I want to check availability of Fragment A in Fragment C.

You can check from anywhere. All you need is reference of the `NavController`.