# Navigate to Existing Fragment Using NavController

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have a complicated structure where a number of `Fragments` link to each other, so using `NavController` I am trying to avoid creating multiple duplicates of the same `Fragment` in the `BackStack`.

I found this post [How to check Navigation Destination is in the NavController back stack or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462370/how-to-check-navigation-destination-is-in-the-navcontroller-back-stack-or-not), which I have implemented as below:

```js
    private fun onSiteItemClicked(item: SiteObject) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClicked() - ${item.siteReference}")
        item.siteID.let {
            businessViewModel.updateCurrentSiteVMLiveData(it)
            try {
                val backStackEntry : NavBackStackEntry = navController.getBackStackEntry(R.id.siteFragment)
                makeToast("backStackEntry = ${backStackEntry.destination.label.toString()}")
                // Navigate to existing Fragment!! HOW TO DO?
            } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_contactFragment_to_siteFragment)
                // Creates new Fragment as one doesn't existing in backstack. THIS WORKS!
            }
            
        }
    }
```

So I have a reference to the `Fragment` in the `BackStack`, but I can't see how to navigate to it..